# SQL Sort table by two columns in turns

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

I have a table A which sorted by id1:
id1  id2

```
1          8
1          9        
3          5        
3          7
6          7
7          9
```

But I want to get this:

```
id1       id2
1          8
1          9
7          9    
3          5        
3          7
6          7
```

At first should be equal values of id1, after this should be equal values of id2 and so on

Comment: A ltile explanation about your logic will be great.

Comment: Are you in Oracle or SQL-server? Better use the right  tags.

Comment: Why don't you just use ORDER BY id2,id1 ?

Comment: Just a remark: A table is *not* sorted. You may happen to get the data ordered by id1, but order is only guaranteed when specifying an `ORDER BY` in your query.

Comment: So "But I want to get this" is supposed to mean "I want to get the data ordered by id2 first and then by id1"?

Comment: Why would 7 - 3 come before 2 - 4, when 2 is lower than 4?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the rules leading to this expected sort order?

Comment: Now you haven't answered any questions and only edited yor request to change the example completely? Even with a desired output matching exactly what you already get???

Comment: Wow, after the edit previous and expected order are exactly the same.

Comment: At first should be equal values of id1, after this should be equal values of id2 and so on

Comment: First update your examles, because they are both the same right now, next tell us the what kind of SQL you are using? (MySQL/MS SQL/Oracle etc)

Comment: Sorting is not essential, I want to get the equal values in the same place

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt work properly

Comment: It would be great if you show me, how split this table into parts. I want to have parts with connection with the value in the previous row. In this example, first part 1-3 rows, second part 4-6 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the asterisks are indicating a connection with the value in the previous row then this will work for your sample data:

**Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT id1, id2
FROM   (
  SELECT id1, id2, ROWNUM rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT *
    FROM   (
      SELECT *
      FROM   table_name
      ORDER BY id1, id2
    )
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       ( PRIOR id1 = id1 AND PRIOR id2 < id2 )
    OR ( PRIOR id1 < id1 AND PRIOR id2 = id2 )
    ORDER SIBLINGS BY id1, id2
  )
)
GROUP BY id1, id2
ORDER BY MIN( rn );
```

**Results**:

```
 ID1 | ID2
-----------
   1 |   2
   1 |   3
   7 |   3
   2 |   4
   2 |   5
   6 |   5
   4 |   7
```

**Update**:

**Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT id1,
       id2,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY grp_id ) AS grp_id
FROM   (
  SELECT id1,
         id2,
         grp_id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id1, id2 ORDER BY rn ) AS first_row
  FROM   (
    SELECT id1,
           id2,
           grp_id,
           ROWNUM AS rn
    FROM   (
      SELECT id1,
             id2,
             CONNECT_BY_ROOT( rn ) AS grp_id
      FROM   (
        SELECT id1,
               id2,
               ROWNUM AS rn
        FROM   (
          SELECT id1,
                 id2
          FROM   table_name
          ORDER BY id1, id2
        )
      )
      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         ( PRIOR id1 = id1 AND PRIOR id2 < id2 )
      OR ( PRIOR id1 < id1 AND PRIOR id2 = id2 )
      ORDER SIBLINGS BY id1, id2
    )
  )
  ORDER BY rn
)
WHERE first_row = 1;
```

**Results**:

```
 ID1 | ID2 | GRP_ID 
--------------------
   1 |   2 |      1
   1 |   3 |      1
   7 |   3 |      1
   2 |   4 |      2
   2 |   5 |      2
   6 |   5 |      2
   4 |   7 |      3
```

Comment: This `CONNECT BY` is oracle or MSQL ?  OP put both tags at begging

Comment: `CONNECT BY` is Oracle syntax for [hierarchical queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/queries003.htm).

Comment: Because OP didnt make clear what db was asking you should indicate that in your answer. Also OP just edit the question and now not sure your premise * about connection is still valid.

Comment: The fact it's Oracle is in there - and it still gets the correct order of results for both the 3rd and 6th edits.

Comment: Yes, you are right and is even in bold and I didnt see it. Shame on me :(

Comment: You understood me perfectly, but i dont know this syntax. Is it Oracle?

Comment: Yes, see my second comment - it is for hierarchical queries.

Comment: Yes,it works, but it would be great if you show me, how split this table into parts. I want to have parts with connection with the value in the previous row. In this example, first part 1-3 rows, second part 4-6 rows

Comment: I mean that there is should be identifier of each group in new table

Comment: Unfortunatelly, your query doesnt work properly...i made table with columns id1(9533684,10044621,10044621) and id2(14521291,14307061,14521291). In result I get two groups instead one

Comment: maybe i should change expr. to:  ( PRIOR id1 = id1)
      OR ( PRIOR id2 = id2 )?

Comment: That would probably work.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT id1, id2 
FROM table 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN id1 < id2 THEN id1 ELSE id2 END), id1, id2;
```

The `CASE WHEN id1 < id2 THEN id1 ELSE id2 END` is used to get the lowest of the two ID's (thanks [@dnouth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880278/sql-sort-table-by-two-columns-in-turns/34880751#comment57499864_34880751)), and you can sort on that.

See **[this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/025ed/1)** for an example.

If you use Oracle, you can try the following:

```
SELECT id1, id2 
FROM table 
ORDER BY LEAST(id1, id2), id1, id2;
```

See **[this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5697/3)**.

Comment: Which is a complicated way for `GREATEST(id1,id2)` in *most* DBMSes or `CASE WHEN id1 < id2 THEN id1 ELSE id2 END)` in *every* DBMS :-)

Comment: @dnoeth The important keyword is **most** in this case he use MSQL query and you dont have `GREATEST` there :( .  So the `CASE` is simple for this case. But yes, this looks liek the right answer

Comment: It was tagged both `SQL Server` and `Oracle`, so it's probably `MySQL` :)

Comment: @dnoeth, it indeed is.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
SELECT id1, id2 
FROM table 
ORDER BY id2,id1
```

And the results are as follows:

[image]

Comment: You can remove the asterix thing. They are only there because of bad editing. Oleg's original post didn't contain them (it had *hidden* markdown asterixes to get the values bold).

Comment: Check the new sample data